# How to consume all messages from RabbitMQ queue using pika

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I would like to write a daemon in Python that wakes up periodically to process some data queued up in a RabbitMQ queue.

When the daemon wakes up, it should consume all messages in the queue (or `min(len(queue), N)`, where N is some arbitrary number) because it's better for the data to be processed in batches. Is there a way of doing this in `pika`, as opposed to passing in a callback that gets called on every message arrival?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [basic.get API](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/blocking_basic_get.html), which pulls messages from the brokers, instead of subscribin for the messages to be pushed

Comment: It will have more number of round trips and not efficient.

Comment: @Prateek I'm not going to argue against using rmq's subscribe API with a large enough QoS to keep a stream of messages up and running, it's the best option for throughput. But, sometimes, you don't care about the throughput, you just want a simple API to fetch messages. The same as you may not need ack, and can enable autoack.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code written using pika. A similar function can be written using `basic.get`

The below code will make use of `channel.consume` to start consuming messages. We break out/stop when the desired number of messages is reached.

I have set a `batch_size` to prevent pulling of huge number of messages at once.  You can always change the `batch_size` to fit your needs.

```py
from pika import BasicProperties, URLParameters
from pika.adapters.blocking_connection import BlockingChannel, BlockingConnection
from pika.exceptions import ChannelWrongStateError, StreamLostError, AMQPConnectionError
from pika.exchange_type import ExchangeType
import json

    def consume_messages(queue_name: str):
    msgs = list([])
    batch_size = 500

    q = channel.queue_declare(queue_name, durable=True, exclusive=False, auto_delete=False)
    q_length = q.method.message_count
    
    if not q_length:
        return msgs

    msgs_limit = batch_size if q_length > batch_size else q_length

    try:
        # Get messages and break out
        for method_frame, properties, body in channel.consume(queue_name):

            # Append the message
            try:
                msgs.append(json.loads(bytes.decode(body)))
            except:
                logger.info(f"Rabbit Consumer : Received message in wrong format {str(body)}")

            # Acknowledge the message
            channel.basic_ack(method_frame.delivery_tag)

            # Escape out of the loop when desired msgs are fetched
            if method_frame.delivery_tag == msgs_limit:

                # Cancel the consumer and return any pending messages
                requeued_messages = channel.cancel()
                print('Requeued %i messages' % requeued_messages)
                break

    except (ChannelWrongStateError, StreamLostError, AMQPConnectionError) as e:
        logger.info(f'Connection Interrupted: {str(e)}')

    finally:
        # Close the channel and the connection
        channel.stop_consuming()
        channel.close()

    return msgs
```

Comment: I can write a similar code using basic get but that will have more number of round trips and not efficient.

Comment: What goes inside `requeued_messages`

Comment: when you cancel the consumer there is a possibility that another msg might have been already pulled, so when we cancel those messages they are requeued and that variable stores the count of such messages.

Comment: In order to truly leverage the throughput provided by the subscription method, you should make sure that the [default QoS](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html#default-limit) is large enough (or use the [QoS method](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.basic_qos) to set it up) and also use a multiack when the whole batch has been processed (not consumed) instead of acknowledging each message independently

Comment: Also, please consider adding some timer or so to interrupt the channel.consume in case the queue has less than batch_size messages. Not sure about how well it behave in python/pika, though

Comment: @JoséM Already taking care for the scenario when "queue has less than batch_size messages"